# What is the first parameter for in the callback function of the autocomplete function?

Tags: ace-editor

What is the first parameter for in the call back function of the autocomplete handler:

I'm looking at the source [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/autocomplete/text_completer.js) and [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/lib/ace/autocomplete) and it doesn't describe anything about it.

```
public function codeCompleter(editor, session, position, prefix, callback):void {
    var row:int = position.row;
    var column:int = position.column;

    if (prefix.length === 0) { 
        callback(null, []);
    }

    var testing:Boolean = false;

    callback(null, [{value:"test"},{value:"test1"},{value:"adding"},{value:"added"}]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the node convention of passing `error, result`.

If autocompleter successfully found list of things to show, it should pass null as a first parameter. Passing the error might be useful in cases when something went wrong, and autocompleter wants to show that instead of empty list, but right now this is not implemented.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you provide an example call? If I pass anything into it my code completion word list doesn't show up. I'd also be happy with a link to the function on github to see what it does?

Comment: Thanks. I've read through that many times this week but I can't trace back where the callback function is defined. I want to see what I can pass into that first parameter. I don't know what node convention means in your answer, that might be where I'm confused.

Comment: the first parameter is the error, if autocompleter successfully found list of things to show, it should pass null as a first parameter.